# AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM) Double cross nested stack reference

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless, aws-serverless

I've two different stacks:

AWS::Serverless::Application 1

AWS::Serverless::Application 2

The first stack needs to import the value of the second stack.
The second stack needs to import the value of the first stack.

How can I do this, it depends on each other.

Comment: This is usually a sign of bad application design. Why do they depend on each other? If they’re that intertwined, why are they two stacks?

Comment: Sounds like it should be a one way dependency if that’s the case. If you want functions that are not tightly coupled to the api, that’s great, why are they dependent on the api then?

Comment: I wanted to separate my Serverless API in one stack, and my Serverless Functions in my other stack. So, I can deploy my Functions first, and connect it to the API later. However, in AWS SAM, when putting the resources together, it will first create the Functions, connect the function to the API and create the functions permission to be called by the API.

Comment: For example, when you have one function to be called by multiple APIs, and you don't want all the resources of both API's in one file (btw, there is a restriction of 200 resources in one file). It would be better to separate it in their own stack. In AWS SAM, the API and the Functions are dependent from each other to create it with the right permissions. https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/866

Comment: Still not seeing why the functions need to know about the api. Sounds like a one way dependency. A basic tenet of application design is to not create circular dependencies. If one exists, it suggests either you should have one module or you should revisit your architectural choices. In this case, I don’t see how a circular dependency would logically be possible if they’re separately managed and deployed. They both need to exist for the other to be deployed which clearly doesn’t work.

Comment: The API needs to know which Functions it should call, based on the paths and the methods. The Functions needs to know which API, to give it the permission to be invoked by the API. Yes, I agree, I know SAM requires you to put both resources in one file (template). But I was looking for other solutions at that moment.